# Find solutions to $4x^2\equiv 1\pmod {29}$

Tags: number-theory

Find the solutions to the congruence:

$$4x^2\equiv 1\pmod {29},\rm{ie},(2x)^2\equiv 1\pmod{29}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solutions $a^{2} \equiv 1 $ mod $29 \equiv (a-1)(a+1) \equiv 0$ mod $29$. Since $29$ is prime, it follows that $a-1 \equiv 0$ mod $29$ or $a+1 \equiv 0$ mod $29$. So we need to solve $2x \equiv 1 $ mod $29$ or $2x \equiv -1 \equiv 28$ mod $29$. The first has solution $15$, the second $14$.

Comment: Sir I have not done these kind of problems, here I have some confusion kindly solve my problems. `1.` Is it necessary for $x$ to be an integer(positive), can it be a real number? `2.` Given a quadratic equation we understand that it will have two solutions at most. Here how you come to know that there will be two solutions. `3.` The solutions of the quadratic equation $4x^2-30$, $4x^2-59$ and many more will also be the solution of given problem. Why you have not included these solutions? Sir kindly reply to the three problems.

Answer (score 2):

$4x^2\equiv 1\pmod {29}$$\implies (2x-1)(2x+1)\equiv 0\pmod {29}$
$\implies(2x+1)\equiv 0\pmod {29} \text{or} (2x-1)\equiv 0\pmod {29}$
$\implies2x\equiv -1\pmod {29} \text{or} 2x\equiv 1\pmod {29}$
$\implies 2x\equiv -1+29\pmod {29} \text{or} 2x\equiv 1+29\pmod {29}$
$\implies2x\equiv 28\pmod {29} \text{or} 2x\equiv 30\pmod {29}$

$\implies x\equiv14\text{or}x\equiv15$(since $\gcd(2,29)=1$)

Comment: Sir I have commented a problem under the answer of (mich95). Please see that and help me to understand my mistake.

Comment: @Singh:We are defining congruence relation for integers only, so $x$ should be an integer(need not be positive) to use modular arithmetic. This might help you:https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic.

Comment: @Singh: Given a quadratic equation, it has exactly two roots. Both of the roots can be complex, or both of them reals or one real root and one complex root. Also both of the roots can be the same. Think, if it was to solve $4x^2\equiv-1\pmod{29}$ can you proceed in the similar manner?

Comment: @Singh: we said $x\equiv14$ and $x\equiv15$ are the solutions, not $x=14$ and $x=15$. $x\equiv14$  have infinite number of solutions in it, and thats the beauty of modular arithmetic.(all congruence I said are modulo 29)

Comment: Thank you sir now I understand what mistakes I was making. Sir I found a similar [problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1336592/solve-3x2-6x-1-equiv-0-pmod-19) and then I thought that if I solve $3x^2-6x-1=0,19,$ or any multiple of 19 and then we can  get to the solution. But I was wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The equation is equivalent to $29 \mid (2x)^2 -1 = (2x-1)(2x+1)$, as 29 is a prime number the last equation is equivalent to
$$\begin{cases}
2x \equiv 1 (29) \\
2x \equiv -1 (29)
\end{cases}
$$
and you should be able to arrive at the solution from here.